# Adding unique values in the output in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'numbers' : [1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3],
'colors' : ['red', 'yellow', 'red', 'green', 'blue', 'purple', 'blue', 'blue', 'green', 'blue', 'purple', 'blue', 'blue', 'purple', 'red']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

temp = df.groupby('numbers').colors.apply(' --> '.join)
```

I got some help with my code earlier but now I'm stuck on another step...
The current output looks like this:

```
1 red --> green --> blue --> blue --> blue
2 yellow --> purple --> blue --> purple --> purple
3 red --> blue --> blue --> green --> red
```

But I need to aggregate the similar values so that the output will look like this:

```
1 red --> green --> blue x3
2 yellow --> purple --> blue --> purple x2
3 red --> blue x2 --> green --> red
```

I've attempted using things like

```
['colors'].count()
```

But this counts all the values in total, when I am looking for duplicate values next to each other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Defining a custom function using `itertools.groupby`:

***Setup***

```
import itertools

def foo(arr):
    for i, g in itertools.groupby(arr):
        l = len(list(g))
        if l > 1:
            yield f'{i} x{l}'   # yield '{i} x{l}'.format(i=i, l=l)
        else:
            yield i

def bar(vals):
    return ' --> '.join(foo(vals))
```

Now `apply`:

```
df.groupby('numbers').colors.apply(bar)
```

```
numbers
1                   red --> green --> blue x3
2    yellow --> purple --> blue --> purple x2
3           red --> blue x2 --> green --> red
Name: colors, dtype: object
```

Comment: I tried running this but I got the error 'invalid syntax' for 'yield f'{i}x{l}'

Comment: Are you using Python 3.6+? I added in a line that works for older versions, just replace the current line with the line in the comment

Comment: I am using Python 3.5.4

Comment: OK.  Then replace the line with `yield '{i} x{l}'.format(i=i, l=l)`

Comment: That worked! Can you explain why this version needs the extra '.format(i=i, l=l)'?

Comment: In Python 3.6, a feature was added called f-strings, which allow for code to be placed directly in the formatted string, and the result of the code is saved in the output.  In earlier versions of Python, you have to use `str.format` to achieve the same behavior